# How do I detect that my page was loaded into a div or not?

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a dynamic website, where only the new content loads, other elements stay the same. The first problem:
I want to detect that for example my home.php was loaded into the index.php's div or not. How can I do that? Because if it's not loaded there, it has to redirect to index.php with the home section. And here's the second problem, if I refresh the page it always shows home as default...
index.php:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content"></div>
<script src="js/general.js"></script>
```

js/general.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // initial
    $('#content').load('home.php');

    //handle menu clicks
    $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('' + page + '.php');
        window.history.pushState('', '', '' + page + '.php');
        return false;
    });
});
```

I tried several ways but it has not succeed..

**UPDATE:**
It's not working. But I'm sure I wrote my question correctly. I want to know how to determine someone who opens home.php directly, and not through index.php. home.php always have to redirect to index.php!! And have to perceive the opened menu.
So, for example, someone's open home.php then it forwards him to index.php with the menu "Home" open.

```
$('#content').load('' + page + '.php', function(response, status, xhr) {
       if (status == "error") {
           alert("Sorry but there was an error: ");
       } else {
           alert("Load was performed.");
       }
    });
```

Only shows error if it's inside index.php. And not useful if I want to prevent home.php from direct opening..

Answer (score 1):

As I am seeing in `jquery` documentation `jquery` provides `callback` function for this.

```
     $('#content').load('' + page + '.php', function(response, status, xhr) {
       if (status == "error") {
           alert("Sorry but there was an error: ");
       } else {
           alert("Load was performed.");
       }
    });
```

Comment: And how can I do it inversely? I mean to drop Load was performed, if load was not happened?

Comment: Furthermore, jQuery.load can get `#content` directly instead of returning the whole page. `$("#content_wrapper").load("/page.php #content",function(response, status, xhr) { /* ...callback... */ });` will replace the entire #content block with the newly loaded one. Keep in mind that any possible events (click, etc) inside the #content block need to be set as you entirely replace the node. - No need for much scripting and loader detections.